# Pyside build.sh Cannot parse file: ../data/typesystem.xml

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am following this tutorial http://lynxline.com/superhybrids-part-2-now-qt-pyside/ I am getting the following output when running build.sh:

```
Fatal error: line=3, column=62, message=Failed to parse: 'typesystem_core.xml'

Cannot parse file: ../data/typesystem.xmlWARNING: Failure to find: pyhybrid/pyhybrid_module_wrapper.cpp
WARNING: Failure to find: pyhybrid/mainwindow_wrapper.cpp
```

In build.sh the following directories are listed:

```
QTGUI_INC=/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers
QTCORE_INC=/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers
QTTYPESYSTEM=/usr/local/share/PySide/typesystems
```

but I do not have these directories. Pyside, Qt, and Python are instaled. Where can I find typesystems, QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OS you are using , but assuming you are using Linux (Ubuntu), the include headers should be installed (assuing Pyside and Qt were installed using the APT package manager) under

```
QTGUI_INC=/usr/include/qt4/QtGui
QTCORE_INC=/usr/include/qt4/QtGui
```

or if done from source:

```
QTGUI_INC=/usr/local/include/qt4/QtGui
QTCORE_INC=/usr/local/include/qt4/QtGui
```

As for the `QTTYPESYSTEM` directory, you need to install the `libpyside-dev` package

Comment: Sanks,That exactly what I need. But I have new problem. In build.sh

 No C++ classes found!
 Cyclic dependency found! Graph can be found at /tmp/qt_temp.T15161
 

Done, 860 warnings (0 known issues)
WARNING: Failure to find: pyhybrid/pyhybrid_module_wrapper.cpp
WARNING: Failure to find: pyhybrid/mainwindow_wrapper.cpp

I dont think it is normal "860 warnings".Same as 
type 'QPyTextObject' is specified in typesystem, but not defined. This could potentially lead to compilation errors

Answer (score 0):

build.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

PROJ_DIR=`pwd`

echo "Building hybrid project."
echo "Project root: " $PROJ_DIR

QT4TYPESYSTEM_DIR=`pkg-config --variable=typesystemdir pyside`
QT4HEADER_DIRS=`pkg-config --variable=includedir QtCore`:`pkg-config --variable=includedir QtCore`/..:`pkg-config --variable=includedir QtGui`

function step_app {
    cd hybrid
    qmake
    make clean
    make
    cd $PROJ_DIR
}

function step_generate {
    cd hybridpy
    shiboken --include-paths=$PROJ_DIR/hybrid:$QT4HEADER_DIRS:/usr/include --typesystem-paths=$PROJ_DIR/data:$QT4TYPESYSTEM_DIR --output-directory=. --debug-level=medium $PROJ_DIR/data/global.h $PROJ_DIR/data/typesystem.xml
    cd $PROJ_DIR
}

function step_wrap {
    cd hybridpy
    qmake
    make clean
    make
    cd $PROJ_DIR
}


echo "Qt typesystem dir: $QT4TYPESYSTEM_DIR"
echo "Qt headers dir:  $QT4HEADER_DIRS"

step_app
step_generate
step_wrap
```